# Reverse order on output of custom values

Tags: php, wordpress

I am pulling out values from a series of custom fields named thumb:

```
<?php
      $mykey_values = get_post_custom_values('preview');
      foreach ( $mykey_values as $key => $value ) {
      echo "<img src='$value' width='590'  />";
      }
?>
```

How do I reverse the order of the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_reverse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php):

```
  $mykey_values = array_reverse(get_post_custom_values('preview'));
  foreach ( $mykey_values as $key => $value ) {
  echo "<img src='$value' width='590'  />";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably `array_reverse` right before your `foreach`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php).

```
<?php
      $mykey_values = get_post_custom_values('preview');
      $reversed_mykey_values = array_reverse($mykey_values);
      foreach ( $reversed_mykey_values as $key => $value ) {
      echo "<img src='$value' width='590'  />";
      }
?>
```